Browser closes connection on chunked data after recieving 6 chunks
I want to send images, videos, audio through TCP in chunks. I wrote this function
but for some reason every Browser I use closes the connection after recieving only a few chunks of data. Is there a limit a Browser receives from a TCP connection?
fn send_chunked(req_path: String, mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<()> {
        let mut f = fs::File::options().read(true).open(req_path).unwrap();
        let mut buf = [0; 1024];
        stream.write_all(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n").unwrap();

        loop {
            match f.read(&mut buf[..]) {
                Ok(0) => {
                    println!("{:?}", &buf);
                    let eof_chunk = b"0\r\n\r\n";
                    stream.write_all(eof_chunk)?;
                    break;
                },
                Ok(1024) => {
                    println!("{:?}", &buf);
                    //println!("1024");
                    let chunk_size = b"1024\r\n";
                    stream.write_all(chunk_size)?;
                    let mut payload = Vec::with_capacity(1026);
                    payload.extend_from_slice(&buf);
                    payload.push(b'\r');
                    payload.push(b'\n');
                    stream.write_all(payload.as_slice())?;
                    buf.fill(0);
                },
                Ok(n) if n < 1024 => {
                    //println!("{}", &n);
                    let chunk_size = format!("{:x}\r\n", n as u64);
                    stream.write_all(chunk_size.as_bytes())?;
                    let mut payload = Vec::with_capacity(n + 2);
                    payload.extend_from_slice(&buf[..n]);
                    payload.push(b'\r');
                    payload.push(b'\n');
                    stream.write_all(payload.as_slice())?;
                }
                Err(e) => return Err(e),
                _ => (),
            }
        }
        
        Ok(())
    }

It prints 6 times '1024' and then says that the host closed the connection plus (os error 10053). I tested how many chunks and how big they should be when only reading from the file. It should be 13 chunks with each 1024 except the last two which are 296, and 0.
Why does my Browser stop the connection? And sorry for this mess.

The chunk size must be written in hex. You do this when the chunk is smaller than 1024 bytes, but for a chunk of 1024 you write the size in decimal ("1024") instead hex ("400"). No idea why you have a special case for 1024, as the case for <1024 would work perfectly even for 1024.
